# How to enlarge hit area of UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm using few gesture recognizers on some views, but sometimes views are too small and it's hard to hit it. Using recognizers is necessary, so how can I enlarge hit area?

Comment: So, you're asking how to enlarge the view?

Comment: No, of course I know how to enlarge frame of view :) I need to enlarge hit frame, without affecting its real frame.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are doing this for a custom `UIView`, you should be able to override the `hitTest:withEvent:` method:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGRect frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, -20, -20);

    return CGRectContainsPoint(frame, point) ? self : nil;
}
```

The above code will add a 20 point border around the view. Tapping anywhere in that area (or on the view itself) will indicate a hit.

Comment: I think it is better to override pointInside because hitTest calls pointInside: recursively on subviews.

Answer (score 6):

Swift version of @rmaddy answer:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let frame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -20, dy: -20);
    return frame.contains(point) ? self : nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a `UIImageView` as a button, you can use the following extension (Swift 3.0):

```
extension UIImageView {
open override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if self.isHidden || !self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.alpha < 0.01 { return nil }

    let minimumHitArea = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    let buttonSize = self.bounds.size
    let widthToAdd = max(minimumHitArea.width - buttonSize.width, 0)
    let heightToAdd = max(minimumHitArea.height - buttonSize.height, 0)
    let largerFrame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: -widthToAdd / 2, dy: -heightToAdd / 2)

    // perform hit test on larger frame
    return (largerFrame.contains(point)) ? self : nil
}
}
```

Similar to the `UIButton` extension [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808503/uibutton-making-the-hit-area-larger-than-the-default-hit-area)

Comment: Error: Declarations in extensions can't override yet

Comment: @MatthewBarker see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616409/declarations-in-extensions-cannot-override-yet-error-in-swift-4