# @objc keyword extension subclass behaviour

Tags: swift, swift4, swift4.1

Can someone explain why `@objc` keyword is needed here to compile the code?

As I understood this keyword is used in order to work ObjC message method dispatch. But this is not an `NSObject` instance.

```
 class MyClass {
 }

 extension MyClass {
     @objc func extensionMethod() { /// THIS LINE
         print("A")
     }
 }

 class SubClass: MyClass {
     override func extensionMethod() {
         print("B")
     }
 }
```

Does `@objc` keyword enable message dispatch as well as `dynamic`? Or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does `@objc` keyword enable message dispatch as well as `dynamic`?

Not usually. Usually, the `@objc` attribute on its own just exposes a given class member to Objective-C – Swift is still free to dispatch to it either using table or static dispatch. You would need to mark the member as `dynamic` if you wanted Swift to use message dispatch when calling it.

However, for a non-final `@objc` class *extension* member, Swift will automatically infer it to be `dynamic`. Why? Because for interoperability reasons, Swift allows `@objc` extension members to override and be overridden (much like how you can override an Obj-C method in a subclass category). In order to achieve this behaviour, Swift relies on Obj-C message dispatch.

Therefore, in an extension, `@objc` infers `dynamic`. You cannot override an extension member without exposing it to the Obj-C runtime because extension members cannot currently be added to Swift class vtables (as Swift vtables currently cannot have members dynamically added to them at runtime).

> But this is not an `NSObject` instance.

On Apple platforms (i.e those with Obj-C interop), *all* Swift classes are exposed to the Obj-C runtime, and all implicitly inherit from a special Obj-C base class called `_SwiftObject`, which conforms to `NSObjectProtocol`. So Swift classes are able to take advantage of message dispatch without having to inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: It seems this is a very nice explanation. But could you provide some proofs?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Unfortunately, I don't believe much of this is officially documented – you have to dig into the compiler/stdlib code to see it, for example [here's where `dynamic` inference takes place](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/01312d9623357672bf1a72215ed88a21590f02c5/lib/Sema/TypeCheckDecl.cpp#L2590), [here's where `_SwiftObject` is declared](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/01312d9623357672bf1a72215ed88a21590f02c5/stdlib/public/runtime/SwiftObject.h).

Comment: what do you mean 'apple platform'? How will this code behave in e.g. Ubuntu?

Comment: @Vyacheslav On Linux, there's no Obj-C interop, so Swift classes won't inherit from `_SwiftObject`, you won't be able to mark things as `@objc` or `dynamic`, and you won't be able to override extension members.

Comment: @Vyacheslav No, selectors are a mechanism used to refer to Obj-C exposed methods, so they won't work without Obj-C interoperability.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Happy to be of help :)

Comment: @Vyacheslav if you look in lldb on a layout of a "pure" swift class than you will see it has a "isa" pointer and the memory layout is basically the same as for the ObjC class. The same memory layout "appears" when a Swift class inherits from NSObject.

Comment: Sorry to bother. I read this, but still not sure if my implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727968/how-to-modify-uibuttons-accessibilitylabel-in-an-extension/50820671#50820671) would work 100%. My question is about **Swift 3**. Can you just confirm if that if I add `@objc open override var accessibilityLabel: String?{...` would it work with no doubt?!

Comment: @Honey No bother, always happy to be pinged with questions :) I wouldn't rely on defining `@objc open override var accessibilityLabel: String?` in a `UIButton` extension, as if `UIButton` adds its own override of `accessibilityLabel`, there's no guarantee that your implementation will be called (in the same way that if you define the same method in two categories of an Obj-C class, there's no guarantee on which implementation will be called). It's only reliable if you can guarantee that there's one implementation for a given class (such as in OP's example as they're overriding in a subclass).

Comment: thanks. So what part of that logic has changed in Swift4?

Comment: @Honey None, as far as I’m aware. The only thing that has changed in Swift 4 is the fact that Swift no longer infers the `@objc` attribute on members of `NSObject` inheriting classes. OP’s example therefore would have compiled in Swift 3 without the explicit `@objc` if `MyClass` inherited from `NSObject` (as the compiler would have inferred the `@objc`). But now the compiler requires an explicit `@objc` to make it clear you’re exposing it to Obj-C, regardless of `NSObject` inheritance.

Comment: This is an old question, but what if you add the keyword `final` to the override method. Does that make it static dispatch?