# how to modify UIButton's accessibilityLabel in an extension

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, swift-extensions

I'm using an analytics tool which logs the `accessibilityLabel` of buttons. 
I'm trying to find a way to update the `accessibilityLabel` without changing my existing code.

For normal buttons I use the `titleLabel.text`. For iconButtons which use their the name coming from image assets I use `accessibilityLabel` itself.

Some issues I faced:

- can't access `accessibilityLabel` within its getter. Because that would recursively look for `accessibilityLabel`.
- So I had to use another property for backing and since this was an extension I wasn't able to use stored properties. Computed properties didn't work either because it would get stuck in the same feedback loop.
- Eventually I hacked my way by using `accessibilityHint`. It's a stored property that I have no use of...

**This works!** Yet I've been [told and read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions) that I **shouldn't** override functions in an extension as that's not reliable. So I'm wondering what I should do?

And if Swift has any mechanism that doesn't involve overriding in UIButton's extension?!

here is my code:

```
extension UIButton{
    private var adjustAccessibilityLabel : String{
        if titleLabel?.text?.isEmpty == false{
            return titleLabel!.text!
        }else if accessibilityHint?.isEmpty == false{
            return accessibilityHint!
        }else{
            return "Empty"
        }
    }

    open override var accessibilityLabel: String?{
        get{
            return "\(self.adjustAccessibilityLabel))"
        }
        set{
            accessibilityHint = newValue // Hacking my way through!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just extends `UIButton` and override it as subclass. `extension` is not meant for overriding stuff.

Comment: Yes but then I would have to change every instance of UIbutton in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fighting the system. You can achieve this using **subclassing**.

To avoid similar problems in the future, always have ALL your `UIButton`, `UITableViewCell`, `UIViewController`, etc subclassed from your *own* base class so you can easily make such universal changes.