# Why is overriding NSViewController methods in an extension allowed?

Tags: swift

TL;DR: Why can you override `NSViewController` methods in a subclass using an extension when the Swift Programming Guide implies that extensions cannot be used to override functions?

In the [Swift Programming Guide - Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) section, it states:

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

However, I routinely override `NSViewController` in an extension on my subclass. Example:

```
class ViewController : NSViewController {}

extension ViewController {
  
  // This is legal and does not generate a compiler error. 
  // The method viewDidLoad() is declared in NSViewController itself.
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  // This is legal and also does not generate a compiler error.
  // The method addChild() is declared in an extension on NSViewController.
  //
  override func addChild(_ childViewController: NSViewController) {
    super.addChild(childViewController)
  }
}
```

If you look at the Swift generated interface for `NSViewController`, the method `addChild` is defined in an extension. So the extension in my subclass is overriding a method defined in an extension in its parent class.

Presumably this is allowed because `NSViewController` is an Objective-C class. Attempting to use the same pattern in a Swift-only `class` yields a compiler error.

But I've found very little documentation on this behaviour and was curious:

- What are the rules for overriding a method in an Objective-C class?
- `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and several other `NSViewController` methods are not defined in an extension whereas most others are. Does it matter if my subclass overrides them in an extension or not?
- I *assume* the `@objc` decorator is playing an important role in this. Is there any documentation out there describing how `@objc` affects `override` such that it us allowed in extensions? Or is this behaviour supported because `NSViewController` is ultimately an `NSObject`?

*macOS 10.15 Beta 5, Xcode 11 Beta 5*

Comment: I think this is (partially?) a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions). To quote from the first answer: "The compiler is allowing you to override in the extension for compatibility with Objective-C. But it's actually violating the language directive." [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151102/objc-keyword-extension-subclass-behaviour?noredirect=1&lq=1) is related too.

Comment: That first question is indeed related, thank you. I still find it quite surprising that the general consensus is "It works, it shouldn't, but it does, you shouldn't do it, but if you do it will work." I see `UIViewController` and `NSViewController` methods being overriden in extensions throughout plenty of sample code.

Comment: Rules are AFAIK the same in Swift as in ObjC: [Overriding methods using categories in ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5272451) This is some distance down the road to UB.