# Raising the icons on UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

`UIToolbar`s normally center their icons vertically. I want to make their icons to be partially outside the bar. See the picture:

[image]

Is it possible to have control over the buttons Y position, overriding the `UIToolbar` default positioning?

Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to achieve this by setting a background for the toolbar that has transparency partway up so it appears as though your buttons extend past the top.

Comment: I thought about this possibility but was trying to see if there was an alternative first. :)

Comment: The problem with trying to move the buttons "above" the top of the toolbar is that it is likely that the portion of the button that is outside of the normal toolbar will not be interactive, since it is not contained within its superview's frame

Comment: ok, but like UIButtons I can extend the touch area to outside the normal size of the buttons. I suppose I can do that too with toolbars.

Comment: How do you do it with `UIButton`?  Is that same interface available in `UIToolbar`?

Comment: you just create a UIButton subclass [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808503/uibutton-making-the-hit-area-larger-than-the-default-hit-area). I think the same principle can be applied to any touch element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `UIToolbar` you can't add `UIButton`s directly, but have to use `UIBarButtonItem`s.

Why not just have a `UIView` as a container for your buttons and then add a background image or another view with the green color behind your buttons?

Comment: I know about the UIBarButtonItem stuff. I think the way to go will be to create a UIView. Thanks.