# How to increase selection area of UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have made the `UIButton` programmatically

```
togglebutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
togglebutton.frame = CGRectMake(42, 15, 80, 21);
[togglebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleview)   
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[togglebutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"squ.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonView addSubview:togglebutton];
```

[image]

It is looked as the right button in above image. Now the requirement is that the selection area of this button should be more than then the uibutton image. So that the user will be able to click the button easily by touching on near by area of particular button.

```
[togglebutton setImageEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake( 0, -30, 0, -25)];
```

I tried to set the `image inset` but it making the `image irregular`. Please look upon this issue.

Comment: How did you choose those insets and what other values did you try?

Comment: Look at this and try changing the view mode of the button image, then it should work with the insets and the image should stay the same - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html

Comment: @Wain I set the image inset with the difference of button and image size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIButton: Making the hit area larger than the default hit area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808503/uibutton-making-the-hit-area-larger-than-the-default-hit-area)

Comment: I recommend this answer [uibutton-making-the-hit-area-larger-than-the-default-hit-area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808503/uibutton-making-the-hit-area-larger-than-the-default-hit-area). Maybe it can help most of us

Comment: Maybe help, my solution on Swift 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45436719/6013170

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the button's `contentEdgeInsets`, for example:

```
toggleButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0); //set as you require
```

Comment: According to the property declaration, you would need negative values for the inset to increase the selection area.
Use this property to resize and reposition the effective drawing rectangle for the button content. The content comprises the button image and button title. You can specify a different value for each of the four insets (top, left, bottom, right). A positive value shrinks, or insets, that edge—moving it closer to the center of the button. A negative value expands, or outsets, that edge.

Comment: You can also set this directly in the storyboard from the xcode gui. To do so select the button you want and choose the "identity inspector", then add a "User Define Runtime Attribute" named "contentEdigeInsets" of type "Rect". This is sometime more convenient than doing it in code.

Comment: FYI: Positive values do increase the tappable area of the button.

Comment: To add on, I just increased button size and then set UIEdgeInsets to positive numbers of how much increased.

Answer (score 18):

For Swift

You can override func 'pointInside' of UIView class to expand clickable area.

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    // padding : local variable of your custom UIView, CGFloat
    // you can change clickable area dynamically by setting this value.

    let newBound = CGRect(
        x: self.bounds.origin.x - padding,
        y: self.bounds.origin.y - padding,
        width: self.bounds.width + 2 * padding,
        height: self.bounds.height + 2 * padding
    )
    return CGRectContainsPoint(newBound, point)
}
```

Use like this,

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    var padding = CGFloat(0) // default value

    //func pointInside at here!!
}
```

When you init your button, set your custom padding.

```
func initButton() {
    let button = MyButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 30, height: 30))
    button.padding = 10 // any value you want
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

then your button is in frame (x: 100, y:100, width: 30, height: 30)

and your button's clickable area might be in the frame with (x: 90, y: 90, width: 50, height: 50)

** Be sure to check overlapping with any other view, because its clickable area is larger than it looks.

**Update for Swift 3**

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let padding = CGFloat(10)
    let extendedBounds = bounds.insetBy(dx: -padding, dy: -padding)
    return extendedBounds.contains(point)
}
```

Comment: This is the ideal solution for use with auto layout.

Comment: also an ideal solution for those who need to adjust a button's image without compromising the hit size

Comment: The selector is not getting called even if the method `pointInside(point:with)` is returning `true`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `contentEdgeInsets` property of the [UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).

Answer (score 3):

in xcode 9 you can do the following:

[image: xcode 9 screenshot]

that means you have to compensate the image offset and content offset to ensure a centered image positioning.

Answer (score 2):

The Below code solves my problem.This is very basic way,
Try this :

```
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 20, 10, 10);  //Change x,y,width,height as per your requirement.
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Objective C**

Create this custom UIButton Class and assign it into your button. Then set these properties values from viewController.

```
//This is .h file
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        @interface CustomButton : UIButton
        @property (nonatomic) CGFloat leftArea;
        @property (nonatomic) CGFloat rightArea;
        @property (nonatomic) CGFloat topArea;
        @property (nonatomic) CGFloat bottomArea;
        @end



        //.m file is following
        #import "CustomButton.h
        @implementation CustomButton

        -(BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
        {
            CGRect newArea = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x - _leftArea, self.bounds.origin.y - _topArea, self.bounds.size.width + _leftArea + _rightArea, self.bounds.size.height + _bottomArea + _topArea);

            return CGRectContainsPoint(newArea, point);
        }
        @end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my button image is small and I want to increase button area while not increasing `uibutton` image size because it will look blurred. So I increased button frame and then set button image `setImageEdgeInsets`. Positive values for `edgeInsets` will shrink and negative values will expand.

```
self.menuButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.menuButton addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(onSideBarButtonTapped:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.menuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 3, 40, 40);
```

Now I am going to shrink image size so that button will not look blurred.

```
[self.menuButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

Answer (score -2):

I would create a UIView around that button so that you can set the size to whatever you want. Then I'd set the UIView's background color to the clear color (do not set opacity to 0 or the gesture won't be recognized)

Then add a UIGestureRecognizer to the uiview to handle the same IBAction

Of course, many people will encourage/prefer the use of the edgeInsets

Comment: this is definitely not the correct way of solving this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example of increasing touchable area of custom UIButton:

```
UIImage *ButtonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
UIButton *myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 25, ButtonImage.size.width/2+10, ButtonImage.size.height/2+10);
[myButton setImage:ButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(crossButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

Hope it would be helpful.