# how to set the values for UIEdgeinset for button

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout, uiedgeinsets, imageedgeinsets

I wanted to increase the button touch area without without actually increasing its original size.

When it comes to insets there are so many in Button and there is no clear documentation I could find on the differences

- Content Insets
- Title Insets
- Image Insets

So later on I thought to try on content inset.
According to other stack overflow answers settings negative value to all the co-ordiantes(left,top,right,bottom) will increase the touch area of button without actually increasing its width and height.

But interfacebuilder doesn't allow me to enter values on all.

for example if i enter -10 in left and I couldn't enter -10 in right and others like that.

I am very much confused on this can somebody help me unravel the complexity

thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249104/how-to-increase-selection-area-of-uibutton

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Thanks but the link does not explain differences and why it not accepts negative values... if you could explain me and put it as answer ,it'd be very much appreciated

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: its not letting me enter -10 in all the fileds in the first place boss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
func setupButton(button: UIButton) {
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)
    button.imageEdgeInsets =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)
    button.contentEdgeInsets =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)
}
```

You can refer [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451223/uibutton-how-to-center-an-image-and-a-text-using-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgei) for more elaborated answer.

Comment: so is it not possible to do in storboard editor .. its not accepting more negative vlaues in the first place

Comment: I am confused what does title vs image vs content insets mean

Comment: its not letting me enter -10 in all the fileds in storyboard