# How can I implement this objC code in ruby

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I am using ruby motion and want to increase the clickable area of a UIView. I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13977921/44286) for this on SO

I'm trying to find out how to do this in ruby.

Basically I want to subclass `UIView` and override the `pointInside` button.

Comment: Which part do you not know how to do? Create a class? Write an instance method?

Comment: I can do those but not sure about the `withEvent`

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation of that code would be:

```
def pointInside(point, withEvent:event)
  margin = 5.0
  area = CGRectInset(self.bounds, -margin, -margin)
  CGRectContainsPoint(area, point)
end
```