# Enlarge button while reducing button's image?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I have a small image button which fits nicely in a certain area of my screen.

The image is a perfect size for viewing, but too small to tap.

Is there any way to make the button itself bigger (hence easier to tap), but make the image smaller, so it looks the right size?

Comment: you can just increase touch area
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808503/uibutton-making-the-hit-area-larger-than-the-default-hit-area

Comment: You need to setImage to button, don't set background image otherwise it will resize according to size.

Comment: @AshwinkumarMangrulkar I am using `Button->Image`, not `Button->Background` ... is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

You just use UIView as a touchView under the your small button.
Like this,

[image]

In this case, I put UIView under the small heart button. And, I implement tap action by UITapGesture.