# Resize the image size of a UIButton to reduce the user from clicking on the empty space next to the button on the right side

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

How do I reduce the image size so that `UIButton` is not pressed when the user click on the extra space of the image on the right side and the button is not using auto constraint

```
barbutton.image = UIImage(named: "backbutton")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

I am trying to decrease my hit area but image insets don't help as the hit area remains the same and the UIButton image reduces which does not help

The bar button:

[image]

Comment: can you show your button?

Comment: barbutton.sizeToFit()?

Comment: just change the hit test area. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808503/uibutton-making-the-hit-area-larger-than-the-default-hit-area

Comment: thanks @yanyabo111 . the link was helpful i was trying to configure to reduce the hit area of the button without reducing the image size of the UIbutton