# Content inset not working Storyboard Xcode8

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uistoryboard, xcode8

Recently I have updated Xcode 7.3 to 8. While opening the project the project settings also have been updated for new Xcode.

Now the insets given for a button image for positioning the image inside button frame is not working as in previous Xcode(7.3) version.

The image insets are given through storyboard. Image was used here to have large clickable area for button than the button image display area. Is there any other options to get it through storyboard.

[image]

Comment: If it was working as expected in 7.3, could it be a bug with the Beta?

Comment: I also got this error in Xcode 8 beta.

Answer (score 53):

In Xcode 8 the button content/title/image insets have moved to the Size Inspector tab:

[image]

Which seems quite logical by the way!

Answer (score 19):

I had this same problem and solved it with image insets and the Horizontal/Vertical Alignment controls. My problem was that I had the wrong alignment controls selected. Once I changed it my insets worked properly for what I was trying to accomplish.

I created a button with an image and the I wanted to shrink the image down to not fill up the entire button So I set the image to the UIButton image property in storyboard and then set the image insets to my liking

[image]

But it did not center my image with the inset of 5 on each side. The image would look like this and that was not what I wanted

[image]

If you change the horizontal/vertical alignment controls I was able to the button image to my desired look I wanted

[image]

Comment: Perfect sollution. Worked for me

Comment: The solution I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

tl;dr: **Set the "Style" to "Default"**

(if you're on Xcode 13, iOS 15 or later)

[image]

Long answer:

I know the very title of this question references Xcode 8 - but this comes up in a Google search and I had issues in Xcode 13 (iOS 15) where the content/title/image insets are not reflected in the storyboard or at runtime. This was due to the new button system, and the solution was to set the button's "Style" to "Default" (it was "Plain").

Comment: That fixed my issues on Xcode 14 for that same issue!!! Thanks

Comment: Been struggling with this for over half an hour and didn't seem to check the style. You're amazing!

Comment: That fixed it fore me except that the filled background with rounded edges are gone :(

Answer (score 0):

Its weird,but it actually works until you add **collectionview** or **tableview** in your Viewcontroller. Try setting the inset without having the scrollview or tableview in your view controller

Answer (score 0):

There is a weird behavior when having a `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` on the scene (as mentioned by @RAHUL JOSHI). [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBo1D.jpg)

Solution: Just ignore the previsualization bug as on runtime this will work normally.

Answer (score -1):

Content inset for button is working perfect in xcode 8 beta.
See below screenshot that i have taken from xcode8 beta.

[image]

Comment: There is no way this is xcode 8 - the inset controls now have their own tab

Comment: Thank you @Dnaso for reply.But if you can check question asked and answer(have clearly mentation about xcode beta8.)have written about xcode beta 8.In xcode beta 8, there is option to give inset as shown in above screenshot.It's not wrong.Answer was given before release of xcode 8.