# Make UIButton bigger than its image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have created a number of `UIButton` in my `iOS` application using the interface builder. Each `UIButton` also has its own image (no title).

I would like to increase the size of the button without disturbing the image size inside of it (making the touch-area bigger without changing the image size).

Is this possible to do using the interface builder? I have played around with pretty much every option in the button page but have not find anything yet?

Comment: Have you considered subclassing?

Comment: take one image view and set your image and set its constraints horizonaly and vertically center to your button and fixed height and with as you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found the answer finally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42176104/3086197)

In Xcode 8 the button `content/title/image` insets have moved to the **Size Inspector** tab but we all know that and it's still not working, but there is one more step in the **alignment** in the below image

[image: illustrating]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set button's  height and width as per require (if autolayout enable) . it should be larger than image size .

And now set button's contentEdges :

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 20, 10, 10);  //Change x,y,width,height as per your requirement.
```

Answer (score 1):

**May be you want to increase the button's focus area, but the button's image still not be changed.**
   **I have two ways.**

**1.** the image you can use UIImageView to addSubView `// To set imageView's position with freedom.`
   Then override the function:

[image]

**2.**  After set button's frame, then set the image's position and size .eg: 
   [button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(up, left,bottom, right)];
   [image]